# How does Java efficiently search jar files for classes?

Tags: java, algorithm, search, jar, performance

Suppose I have 500 jar files linked to my program totaling over 500 MB (size of all the jars, not each one) and my program makes a call to a class located in one of them. How does Java search through jars for a class, and what is the efficiency of this? O(n)? O(log(n))?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Java looks in the internal directory structure of the jar for an exact match on the fully qualified name. It looks; it does not search. If you have 500 jar files on the classpath, Java will look in them one by one in the specified order until it finds a match. If the jar containing a given class is the last one, Java will look in the 500 jar files. So I guess it's O(n).

**UPDATE:** The behavior described above is the **default** behavior. However, as Hassan pointed out, this can be optimized by providing an [JarIndex](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jar/jar.html#JAR%20Index) in the root jar file allowing the classloader to find the proper jar file with a simple lookup on a package name.

Comment: In Java 7, they are trying to redeem that by supporting a module system, similar to OSGi

Comment: @Hassan. Indexes are optional, default is indeed linear: The new class loading scheme is totally backward compatible with applications developed on top of the current extension mechanism.  When the class loader loads the first jar file and an INDEX.LIST file is found in the META-INF directory, it would construct the index hash table and use the new loading scheme for the extension. Otherwise, the class loader will simply use the original linear search algorithm.

Comment: @Hassan This information is **not** outdated, this is the default behavior and I've almost never seen JAR index. Maybe reconsider your vote and your understanding of this.

Comment: @Pascal, your answer reads like a totality -- you preclude the fact that indexing might exist. You should have posted the entire picture -- since the OP is worried about efficiency .

Comment: @Hassan Sorry but I'm describing the **default** behavior which seems to be what the OP is asking for. What you are describing is the exception.

Answer (score 7):

**By default it used to be linear; however, since [JDK 1.3](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jar/) a JAR index can be embedded in the first JAR file of an application.**

This means that if the index is embedded into the JAR file the class loader can efficiently find all the classes distributed over multiple JAR files belonging to the application.

link to [SUN Resource](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/guide/jar/jar.html) on JAR Indexing. Note: non-class resources don't seem to be covered.

Comment: Do you believe that the use of indexes is common? I think still linear behaviour is default, you need to add an index, and many folks don't.

Comment: All zips have an index at the end of the file anyway, so it doesn't make much difference.

Comment: hmm, It seems ANT defaults http://ant.apache.org/manual/CoreTasks/jar.html to false for index generation in JAR files. I wonder what IDE's do ?

Comment: @Hassan, @djna, Out of 342 jars in my maven repo, only 2 had INDEX.LIST!  It's not common to generate those unfortunately.

Comment: Generating an index is application specific as you can't predict which JAR will be on the classpath. Using index is absolutely not common and is absolutely not the norm. According to the link your provided yourself, the idea was initially to help applets but, who does use them nowadays?

Comment: Applications which have a huge common source base  -- picture an extensible engine -- such as an IDE or a web-server; such applications have # a huge stable set of classes in stable JAR files which will be pulled in every time the application is started. These JAR files will therefore benefit from indexing. On the other hand the plugin's might not.