# Classloader finding a class from a huge list of jars

Tags: java, optimization, classloader

I have a java web app which have in its \WEB-INF\lib\ folder around 679 jars. I have read the classloaders (the app is using TomcatEmbeddedWebappClassLoader) read in alphabetical order this folder in order to find a class and load it. If this is the way, a class that its contained in the last jar will take much more time to find it by the classloader than its contained in the first jar in the list.

- Is this true that the classloader reads the contents of lib folder in alphabetical order?
- Is not there any optimization in order the classloader finds a class in a huge list of jars? Or it just unzips jar by jar in order to find the class?

Thanks

Comment: Does this allow your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59242577/why-my-springboot-with-embbeded-tomcat-too-slow-when-process-first-request?

Comment: Hi, it explains about optimization but not explains about the the reading order of jars

Comment: About optimization, I found an answer here too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020800/how-does-java-efficiently-search-jar-files-for-classes