# How does JVM find a class file among a list of JARs?

Tags: java, jar, jvm, classloader

Based on my understanding, Java launcher finds a class file by searching through classpath, which can include a list of JARs (ref https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/findingclasses.html). My question is that given a list of JARs and a class to look for, does Java search each JAR one by one sequentially, or if not, how does it find the right class file? Does it cache anything in the process, e.g. directory structure from JARs? If the list of JARs is very long, could that cause issue in performance or memory?

I did saw this post: [How does Java efficiently search jar files for classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020800/how-does-java-efficiently-search-jar-files-for-classes), but there were no references on the default behavior or what optimization is/can be done.

Comment: `Does it cache anything` I assume it caches the list of classes found in all Jars and all directories.  That would be the smart way of doing it.  But I'm not sure I can answer 100% how this works.  Mostly though I don't worry about it, I've yet to have a serious problem that looked like it was caused by long class loading.

Comment: If you want to know the implementation, then you can always look at the source code. [OpenJDK is on GitHub](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk). Start with `java.lang.ClassLoader` and then look at the various subclasses, such as those in the [jdk.internal.loader](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/tree/master/src/java.base/share/classes/jdk/internal/loader) package. Note it would be easier to navigate the source code with an IDE compared to online.

Comment: Thank you all for the comments. I'll take a look at the reference and source code mentioned. I asked this question because we got a weird too many open files exception, and some people suggested it could be due to large number of jar files as dependencies (1000+), which may be opened at the same time when JVM loads classes. Hence I wanted to get a better understanding of the class loading process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is rough answer, sorry for that. But it might be better than nothing, so here we go.

So when you're referring some class that JVM did not load yet, JVM indeed starts looking through class path, iterating over its items, one by one. If you're referring a.b.C, JVM looks for an entry a/b/C.class.

Classpath could consist of many different things. It's abstracted by classloader actually which can do anything, e.g. download classfile over the Internet or select it from the database. But usually it just looks inside JAR files (or inside directories which are valid classpath entries as well).

JAR files are ZIP files and ZIP files have header which allows for relatively quick lookup. It's not super performant, so if your classpath is huge, you might get some performance boost with combining it into one uberjar. Also you might get some performance boost if you would replace jars with extracted folders. But don't take it as advice, most likely boost will be negligible.

After ClassLoader located .class file, it reads its content and "sends" its bytes it to the JVM. It can also alter those bytes before "sending" them to the JVM. So you might achieve some magic things with those magic classloaders. But ordinary classloaders don't do that.

After JVM got those bytes, it parses them, verifies, may be compiles and in the end this class becomes loaded inside JVM address space in some very optimized for execution form. From now on this class will be looked up "instantly".

I think that JVM can also unload unused class if it's not referenced in the program, so I suppose that this process could repeat for the same class. But it's not something you should worry about.

Another thing to keep in mind is that classpath is Java 8 thing. It still could be used in modern Java, but since Java 9 module path appears which could be used with class path in parallel (or as a replacement). It's my understanding that those are similar when it comes down to low level details like I described above, but it's worth to remind, I guess. I think that most programs didn't embrace modules yet, but I don't have statistics.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is really helpful. I have a follow up question. When 2 classes need to be loaded, are they loaded concurrently or sequentially, e.g. if class A and class B need to be loaded, would JVM find file for class A first, load it and then find file for class B, or otherwise?

Comment: Class unloading is only possible when a class loader (and all of its defined classes) is unreachable. Further, class loading with modules works differently. Since within one module layer, package names must belong to a single module without ambiguity, it’s possible to derive the correct module from the qualified class name alone, even before the class has been loaded. Therefore, a requested class belonging to a module can be loaded from the module’s source directly, without going through a search path.